# How to style a data that is taken from JSON file, locally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

How to style a data that is taken from JSON file and generated dynamically with javascript? For example, when i take a 2 texts, i want to style them differently

```
 "<p class='nameMovie'>"
                + data[ i ].name + "  " + data[ i ].year + "  " + data[ i ].gender + "  " + data[ i ].runtime +
 "</p>"
```

In this code i have text like 
this:

```
Godzilla 2014 Fantasy|Action|Sci-fi 2h 3min
```

How i can for the year, gender and runtime to be under Godzilla

Something like this

```
Godzilla 2014 
Fantasy|Action|Sci-fi 2h 3min
```

Comment: The same way that you would do it if you were writing the HTML by hand.

Comment: Don't concatenate data into HTML.  You must escape that data for use in HTML... better yet, set the text of your element so no HTML parsing even has to occur.

Comment: Then how to target a specific text in p?

Comment: It is hard to understand your question, but if I understand correctly you should create two different elements, and give each it's own style. If you're interested in templates and apps, maybe you should read about ReactJS or AngularJS

Comment: Movies don’t have a gender; what you mean is called genre.

Comment: @Bokchee88 you can alwas wrap each part of those in <span> tags and have different classes for each :) like .year, .genre etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to style different parts of the text in different ways is to wrap them all in their own elements and give them separate class names.

e.g.

```
<p class="movie">
    <span class="movieName">Godzilla</span> <span class="movieYear">2014</span>
    <span class="movieGenre">Fantasy|Action|Sci-fi</span>
    <span class="movieRunningTime">2h 3min</span>
</p>
```

You can then experiment with the css to get it how you want.
You might also want to try replacing `<p>` with `<section>`, or wrap a `<header>` around the Name & year elements.

As an aside. I would recommend looking into using a template language like mustache (https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) instead of manually writing the html in javascript. Such libraries will correctly escape the data when printing to the screen stopping weird bugs and xss attacks.